# Is it possible to send and receive funds from a wallet(have control) in a smart contract?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, web3js

Is it possible in Solidity for a smart contract to be able to interact with a **specific wallet** in such a way that it can pull money from it, and send money to it at any time it needs to? In this particular scenario, there will be a **treasury wallet**, that I want the smart contract to be able to **pull from** and **send to** at any time it needs to. Is this something that's possible with a few approvals, or perhaps is there a better, more standard way to resolve the problem that I'm having?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The treasury wallet needs to do ERC-20 token `approve()` on the specific wallet and then it can pull money.

For further details, check out EIP-20 spec.

Comment: Would it be also possible to pull Ether, or only ERC 20 tokens?

Comment: It's not possible to pull ETH.

Comment: Then we'd have to pull something like WETH right?

Comment: That's correct @BrickleRex